# DropDownList ASP.NET custom items

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you advise me how I can add new field to DropDownList items
as I see class ListItem is sealed and it cannot be inherited

I need do this

```
DropDownList dd = new DropDownList();
dd.Items.Add(new ListItem(Text = "", Value = "", **myField=""**)));
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is sealed, so you can't inherit from it and add new property. However, you can use `Attributes` and add `myField` as an attribute to `ListItem` and work with that.

```
DropDownList dd = new DropDownList(); 
ListItem newListItem = new ListItem(Text = "", Value = "");
newListItem.Attributes.Add("myField", "valueForMyField");
dd.Items.Add(newListItem);
```

Comment: I think to use Attributes field but there is a long way to solve this problem. Create New DDL control and rewrite all fields and methods

Comment: @vit2708 not sure why you want to go that way, why do you think creating new DDL control is better than using `Attributes`, but you should know better, so good luck with that.